# Facebook Android SDK 3.0 import from git fails

Tags: android, facebook, eclipse

trying to import facebook for android 3.0 sdk, threw the folloing error:

```
01-11 15:37:15.394: E/AndroidRuntime(408): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-11 15:37:15.394: E/AndroidRuntime(408): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.facebook.samples.hellofacebook/com.facebook.samples.hellofacebook.HelloFacebookSampleActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.facebook.samples.hellofacebook.HelloFacebookSampleActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.facebook.samples.hellofacebook-1.apk]
01-11 15:37:15.394: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1569)
01-11 15:37:15.394: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
01-11 15:37:15.394: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
01-11 15:37:15.394: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
01-11 15:37:15.394: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-11 15:37:15.394: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
01-11 15:37:15.394: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
01-11 15:37:15.394: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-11 15:37:15.394: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-11 15:37:15.394: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
01-11 15:37:15.394: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
01-11 15:37:15.394: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-11 15:37:15.394: E/AndroidRuntime(408): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.facebook.samples.hellofacebook.HelloFacebookSampleActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.facebook.samples.hellofacebook-1.apk]
01-11 15:37:15.394: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
01-11 15:37:15.394: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
01-11 15:37:15.394: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
01-11 15:37:15.394: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
01-11 15:37:15.394: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1561)
01-11 15:37:15.394: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  ... 11 more
```

importing via git fails due to project settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to overcome the errors right click on each sample project->android tools->add support library,
and fix project properties under the same menu.

In addition, don't forget adding android-support-v4 to facebook's lib to project's build path settings.

Answer (score 1):

You can also go to project properties -> Java buildpath -> order and export and tick the android-support-v4.jar